# Failure of education system

Tags: soft-question, advice

I think the education system in my country has developed my mindset in a way that has hindered my mathematics education.
(My questions are at the end.)

I am a senior year highschool student in iran,(majoring in mathematics/physics),and I feel like that I am not being taught proper mathematics.
As an example,consider the formal definition of a limit.

The usual epsilon-delta approach.in school,this definition was completely ignored and was substituted with a "dumbed down" version involving sequences.

We also skip lots of proofs and are said to just "accept" whatever we are being taught.

And we cover a lot of math,
(single variable calculus,elementary linear algebra,analytic geometry,elementary number theory,graph theory,probability theory,set theory,and etc ...)

Another example was the defintion of distance in graphs.
It was said that it had the properties like the trinagle inequality,...
With no justification.

Most of the excercises  and problems we are dealing with are computational,
And don't feel like being math.

I am afraid that with time,I will have developed gaps in my mathematical knowledge,not allowing me to prove or justify any statement I intuitively understand,or not have the enough rigorous arguments to do so.

Part of the reason we are taught this  way is because of this 
"Monster Standard exam" called "konkur".it is a national examination and it determines which unversity you are going to be applied to and etc,...

So my question is :How can I avoid the gaps ? I also do not have time as to read "enough" of good calculus or other textbooks(like apostol or spivak),and I have to make a compromise between a good university ,or a solid math foundation.

Can I resort to autodidactism?Or is it too risky?

Thanks in advance.

Note:I intend to major in pure mathematics.

Comment: Supposing you get into a good university, will it be possible to build that "real"/rigorous math foundation there? I think in the U.S., rigorous math is typically not introduced before college.

Comment: (Note: I don't know what the educational system in Iran is like, so my response will assume that it is analogous to the US system.)  That just sounds like regular high school mathematics to me.  Of course they don't fill in all the gaps -- that's what college is for!

Comment: I'm in Canadian engineering and never learned the epsilon-delta definition of the limit. It isn't really all that important in the functionality of the limit, so I see why they skipped it. Anyway, in high school, I never learned linear algebra, number theory, ect. I just learned how to work with elementary functions, calculus, and vectors. Your school sounds more robust than mine was.

Comment: If your university was anything like mine was, they will assume you don't know much. They will re-teach you calculus from the limit up, and probably include the epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: @Bye_World Prestigious universities in iran are paid by the government,others are not.And most of those "good" universities are only interested in those with a high mark in "konkur". But "konkur" involves a lot of other subjects,which really are irrelevant to my major,like Religion ,philosophy,psychology,literature,etc... Which i think are good ,but why on earth are they included in the examination?

Comment: @LoganLuther Well then my advice is to specifically study for the konkur.  As Kaynex said, usually universities teach you from the ground up anyway.  And if that's not the case at the "prestigious" universities of Iran, you can always take less classes the first term or two so that you have extra time to really get a grip on the material.  But don't worry so much about whether you know enough for the university courses right now -- just make sure you know enough to do well on the konkur as that's the more pressing concern.

Comment: As a student you can't change the system, so you need to work within it. I suggest you use your spare time to study up on the subjects in which you have no interest but which are part of the "konkur". View it as a challenge. As soon as you pass this hurdle, you can then focus on what you love. Such is often the case in life.

Comment: @Bye_World Great,but this question came to my mind:  if I for any reason ,do Not get accepted in those good universities,is it going to have a huge impact on my "Mathematical" future,or not? Also note that I don't really just sit down  and do nothing but I do a lot self-learning myself.

Comment: So much can be said on this topic so in order to avoid a long winded opinion based essay I shall say that here in Canada (and I might assume in other nations as well) there are a lot of university professors who wish to change the high school mathematics curriculum to provide solid foundations.

Comment: This does not look unusual for the high school level. It has been a trend in my country to make the study of math in high school less and less abstract for the last 40 years or so. We blame it either on the political will to make everyone succeed, or on anglo saxon influence. I don't think the latter is a problem in Iran. You should rather blame parents and politicians who want good stats for all at the konkur

Comment: @LoganLuther I really couldn't say.  Just do the best you can and hope it works out for the best.  That's all I can recommend.

Comment: @Vincent Right exactly,they only want results(physicists and engineers in nuclear power plants;) ,and understanding is just Non-existent.

Comment: @Plopperzz I would appreciate a thorough answer (:

Comment: @LoganLuther This has nothing to do with nuclear power plants (which are full with people knowing maths). I am french and our education ideal was to take the best people at school regardless of how much money their parents own, we call this republican elitism. Studies were hard and abstract. Then, unemployment and lack of state money made politicians want to reform high school. With each reform, in order to show results, they made studies easier. And the word elitist got a bad reputation because of financiary elitism. There are several other factors you could consider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can understand your frustrations, but I wouldn't worry yet. Focus on your current studies. Immerse yourself in reading when you have time, and do your best in preparation for the Konkur examination.

*I am a senior year highschool student ... I feel like that I am not being taught proper mathematics... We also skip lots of proofs.... Most of the excercises and problems we are dealing with are computational.*

This is completely normal at the high school level. Remember, *you* may want to become a mathematician, but that skill set is *not* relevant to the majority of your peers.

*I am afraid that with time,I will have developed gaps in my mathematical knowledge,not allowing me to prove or justify any statement I intuitively understand,or not have the enough rigorous arguments to do so.*

I wouldn't expect a HS student, even a superior one with a real talent for math, to be able to do this for proofs beyond simple algebraic and geoemetric exercises.

Your curriculum may be accelerating through a multitude of concepts and skimming past details in an effort to introduce you to the material. I agree that this approach has its downsides, but **high school is an introduction**. In university, you will be revisiting these same concepts in greater depth. You'll be better able to set your own learning schedule then.

Again, in the interim, focus on the curriculum. You may wish to seek out math club and competitions as well for further enrichment prior to university.

Comment: When I finally got to university, I realised I had no idea what math was about. Even though I had read books about it and talked to people who tried to convey the difference between HS and college to me,I learned that higher math is nothing like High School. And I mean that in the most positive way imaginable.